# Neo4j Cypher Console Changing Database

Tags: neo4j

I've just started to learn the Neo4j graphs db, i am a .net developer and i have downloaded the .net version also the sample MVC project for .net (hour ago), I manage to make the project run and playing with it. Upon playing with the Cyphers Console, somehow i cant find the data's from the sample, maybe the default database of the console is pointing to the default db, how do i move to the database that is created by my sample project. is there such thing as database/schema here just like in MSSql/MySQL that tables are grouped by database? 
thanks for response.

Comment: There is no solution for this yet? Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392478/2048848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `neo4j-server.properties` in `conf` folder in your DB folder, and search for `org.neo4j.server.database.location` and make sure it's pointing to the output folder you just created..

Comment: Hi Mohamed. 
thanks for that. so there's no way to do that directly from cypher console?seems like a little bit hassle, hope that in the future, they allow us to modify it directly from the console.
thanks anyway.