# Anyway to have multiple databases on a neo4j instance?

Tags: neo4j

Coming from a relational database mindset, it seems odd that one only one one graph db per instance of neo4j. Is the idea that we do multiple subgraphs starting from root ?

Thanks

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252968

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The concept of "root" node is going away. There are many problems with this, most of which revolve around node density.

I believe the heart of your question is around database design, and whether it is smarter to have several graph database instances, or one instance with several subgraphs.

Really it's up to you, but I would go with the subgraph idea as it allows some of your data to be shared in the same connection, and Neo4j doesn't really any performance penalties if you do this, provided you keep them separated, then the only problem you'll eventually run into is the max size of nodes/relationship, but this is an artificial limit that will be bumped up later.

Comment: I see it's still the only answer available. Do you have any questions about the design?

Comment: no I am clear now. Sub graphs make perfect sense and not having a root node helps. Just sucks that I can't work on multiple projects in tandem as I only have one database. However I think as long as they don't relate, I can have as many nodes as I want.

Comment: Yeah, there won't be any performance degradation because Neo4j keeps most of that stuff as a length delimited array on disk anyways, so accessing Node 1 incurs the same cost as accessing Node 1000000.

Comment: This is very strange to me. If want to work on 2 projects, with no relation between then, in MySQL I can just create another schema, give distinct permissions and to whatever I want. I can't do the same in neo4j? Bizarre...

Comment: @Murta Realistically, what you can do is create 2 separate disconnected graphs in the same storage space. This is almost akin to creating separate schema's in SQL.

Otherwise, you could also just create 2 separate graphs, which will be stored in completely different disk locations.

Comment: @Nicholas they don't need to be in the same storage space if I could easily alternate between then. In Microsoft SQL I just write `USE DATABASE X` or use dot notation to walk between distinct schemas. I'm looking for an equivalent way to do that in neo4j.

Comment: You could use the same storage space and your `USE DATABASE X` would essentially just be your starting node. But I haven't use Neo4j in a long while and from what I remember they removed secondary indexes, which would have let you do this. I'm not sure how helpful I can be now

Comment: @Nicholas what I feel unconfortable is that, Imagine I'm playing with Movie Graph Example, and now I want to play with another distinct graph (no relation among then). I just can't do this in a simple way.

Comment: the problem with subgraphs in a multi-tenant app is that you can't give users access to run cypher queries because then they can see data in subgraphs that belong to other tenants, unless you get into the messy business of performing surgery on their queries. and running a separate instance per user would mean setting up thousands of instances, which really isn't feasible

Comment: there can be another use case which requires support for multiple databases. If i want to partition my data by time, I would create multiple databases, so that after some time, it can be deleted as well.

Answer (score 4):

If it is only for development, you can use [neo4j-instance](https://github.com/niterain/neo4j-instance), it helps me work on several neo4j databases at once (at the same time, basically setting each on a different port), and it flows a lot better than adding a label to differentiate between different schema, or prefixing nodes with the scheme name.  Since, you do not have to change how you interact with the neo4j databases because they are still separate databases on different ports.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Odd, I gave the name of the program, and the link, and what it does for the user, and how it differs from the way neo4j recommends to set up multiple schema in their system.   It is more than a link-only answer.

Comment: @NiteRain My interpretation is that no you didn't - the post, in its current form, summarises as "here's the name of a tool, I found it useful because it's better than these two other ways" but doesn't give any detail about what it actually is or how it is different (I believe it is a bash script allows rapid switching between database instances, but I'm not sure about if it allows them to run concurrently else does a quick shutdown/start for example). Edit: only noticed the timings after posting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I have recently created multiple neo4j instance in pytest session level fixture , suppose you want to run multiple neo4j instance in localhost, here assuming host is single (localhost), and if you see the neo4j conf file($neo4j_home/conf/neo4j.conf) , default configurations are for http port 7474 and for bolt 7687 , Suppose one neo4j is running with http port 7474 , now you can not run another neo4j instance with 7474 , you have to change the port in neo4j.conf then you can start another instance , to resolve this

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 0))
sock.listen(1)
port = sock.getsockname()[1]
```

It will give you the free port and need to change this in neo4j.conf in runtime
now lets see this pytest fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def neo4j_graph_instance(csv_node_file, csv_relation_file):
    instancesDirectory = os.path.join(PATH_TEST_DIR, "neo4j_instance_acceptance")
if not os.path.exists(instancesDirectory):
    os.makedirs(instancesDirectory)

archive_file = "neo4j-community-3.2.1-unix.tar.gz"
filename = instancesDirectory + "/" + archive_file

if (os.path.isfile(filename)) == True:
    try:
        with TarFile.open(filename, "r:gz") as archive:
            archive.extractall(instancesDirectory)
            print ("successfully extracted")

    except IOError:
        print "file is not there"
else:
    try:
        uri = "http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-3.2.1-unix.tar.gz"
        urlretrieve(uri, filename)
        try:
            with TarFile.open(filename, "r:gz") as archive:
                archive.extractall(instancesDirectory)
        except IOError:
            print "file is not there"
    except IOError:
        print "Could not connect to internet to download the file"

neo4j_home = os.path.join(instancesDirectory, "neo4j-community-3.2.1")
neo4j_import_dir = os.path.join(neo4j_home, "import")
neo4j_inst = Neo4jInstance(home=neo4j_home)

neo4j_inst.set_config("dbms.connector.http.listen_address", ":%s" % get_open_port())
neo4j_inst.set_config("dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address", ":%s" % get_open_port())
neo4j_inst.set_config("dbms.security.auth_enabled", "false")
neo4j_inst.set_config("dbms.connector.https.enabled", "false")

# db loading mechanism #
# Rajib: I am getting csv files fixture and copying them in neo4j import dir  in run time.
# Then getting bolt uri for that active instance  , and executing the command 'load_db_script'.
# At the end I am returning one Graph instance with fully loaded with csv files.


neo4j_inst.start_neo4j_instance()
time.sleep(15)
#:todo need to avoid sleep , instead check socket connection to desired host and port
print "copying csv files to neo4j import direcotry"

copy_script = "cp %s %s %s" % (
    csv_node_file, csv_relation_file,  neo4j_import_dir)
call(copy_script, shell=True)
print "successfully copied to neo4j import directory "
neo4j_inst_bolt_uri = "bolt://localhost:%d" % neo4j_inst.get_bolt_port()
load_cypher_file = os.path.join(DMS_PATH, "load_csv.cypher")
load_db_script = "cat %s | %s -a %s --format verbose --debug" % (
    load_cypher_file, neo4j_inst.cypher_shell_script(), neo4j_inst_bolt_uri)
call(load_db_script, shell=True)
neo4j_inst_http_port = neo4j_inst.get_http_port()

yield Graph(host='localhost', http_port=neo4j_inst_http_port, bolt=False)

print "running teardown methods"

neo4j_inst.stop_neo4j_instance()
neo4j_inst.delete_store()
```

So every time it will give you a fixture with neo4j instance where port will be assigned in run time with fully loaded database.