# Multiple Databases in neo4j using py2neo

Tags: mysql, database, neo4j, py2neo

Is it possible to create multiple databases or instances in neo4j, similar to the way one can create multiple databases in mysql?  I found the commentary at the link below, but despite the promising title, it did not seem to answer my question.  I am running the community version of neo4j, version 1.9.5 on a Mac with py2neo REST interface.

For additional context, I might want to create one database (or graph instance) for mapping nodes and relationships in a work email/contact list, and a completely separate instance for a personal family tree.  I tried adding a filename to the instantiation of the GraphDatabaseService method, like so:

graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://`localhost:7474`/db/data/graph.db")

But that did not work.  Obviously, I am new to graph databases and neo4j, but I have had some previous experience in the relational database area, primarily mysql. Once again, the Q&A in the link below did not seem to completely answer my question.

Thanks.

[Anyway to have multiple databases on a neo4j instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392478/anyway-to-have-multiple-databases-on-a-neo4j-instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one database per port in neo. You can spin up multiple processes listening on multiple ports, if needed.

Comment: Thanks very much.  That piece of information connected the dots for me.  I found the information in the link below which indicates how to add ports, so I think I should be good to go.  Thanks again. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/server-installation.html#_mac_osx